# Move a row in Woocommerce checkout page after the total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need to exchange two of the rows in my checkout-review-order-table (taxes and total price) - I want the taxes displayed above the total price and then I need an info text below the total price and in an additional row.

It would be great if there was a possibility to solve the problem in the functions.php

[screenshot checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBMat.jpg)

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Woocommerce checkout page, you need to override the template `checkout/review-order.php` [**via the theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

You will have to move **the Tax block**:

```
    <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) : ?>
        <?php if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
            <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : ?>
                <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo sanitize_title( $code ); ?>">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <tr class="tax-total">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

after the **Total block**:

```
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

    <tr class="order-total">
        <th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>

<!-- #### ====> IN HERE <==== #### -->
```

It will work nicely. It's not possible to do it in another way.

---

Documentation: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)